# How can I define a scope for OR operator in the pattern?

Tags: php, regex

First of all, please take a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/Aoqkh4/1):

```
/foo|bar/
```

In the pattern above, `|` refers to the `foo`, So the scope of `OR` is everything which is in its back *(from the beginning til `|`)*. How can I change that scope?

For example, I want to match both `foo1` and `foo2` in [this](https://regex101.com/r/Aoqkh4/4). And this is my pattern:

```
/foo1|2/
```

But as you see in my demo, my pattern matches both `foo1` and `2` *(not `foo2`)*. How can I define this scope for `OR` operator: "just one previous character" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `foo(1|2)`, `/(foo(1|2))/`, or `/(foo1|foo2)/`.

Your pattern, `/foo1|2/`, matches `foo1` or `2`, whereas `/foo(1|2)/` matches `foo1` or `foo2`.

Comment: I see, so I can define an scope by parenthesis `()` .. thank you, upvote

Comment: That's right, but more specifically, using parentheses defines a group of characters. Please accept my answer if you're satisfied :)